# List() class's extension methods not accessible

Tags: c#, extension-methods, intellisense

I am writing a **Windows 8.1 Universal app**. In the **shared project**, I have an object of [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and want to access the [ElementAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method.

But the method is not showing up in the Visual Studio 2013's suggestions. If I ignore this and enter it myself, the *red squiggly lines* showing error appear below **ElementAt** and the project doesn't build. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to add

    `using System.Linq;`. It's in `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Comment: @avinash Install ReSharper, it solves more than a few irritations ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of multiple other questions, but I can't find them...

Comment: If you have `List<T>` you can use `list[index]`. Why to go behind linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Linq  [`Extension methods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) make sure you include the [`System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.Aspx) namespace.

Comment: If you have System.Linq imported or VS is not giving you the suggestion to import System.Linq you probably forgot to use await on an async method that returns Task<IEnumerable<>> as you were assigning to a dynamic var?  var myList = _myAsyncMethod();  Should be var myList = await _myAsyncMethod();

Answer (score 2):

Add `using System.Linq`. What you are trying to use is what is known as an extension method and that is located in a differnt namespace as it is not actually a method on the List object itself.

You have linked the documentation yourself. Have a look at then namespaces and you will see where you have gone wrong.